# How to avoid displaying plot Ecdf Hmisc?

Tags: r, plot, hmisc

I'm trying to do something very simple:

I'm using the library `Hmisc` in order to use the `Ecdf` function to get the `x` and `y` values that the function returns, but even when I assign it to a variable, the default plot is displayed.

```
library("Hmisc")
ecdf1 <- Ecdf(F) # Plot is displayed
```

How to avoid displaying the plot and only get the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `pl=FALSE`

```
ecdf1 <- Ecdf(F, pl=FALSE)
```

From `Ecdf` help file you can read:

```
set to F to omit the plot, to just return estimates
```